# Как получить значение из input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

```js
$('.btn-number').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
  type = $(this).attr('data-type');
  var input = $("input[name='" + fieldName + "']");
  var currentVal = parseInt(input.val());

  if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
    if (type == 'minus') {

      if (currentVal > input.attr('min')) {
        input.val(currentVal - 1).change();
        var min = currentVal - 1;

        console.log(input);

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'index.php?route=report/forming_order/update&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
          data: {
            "min": min
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('#min').html(data);
          }
        });



      }
      if (parseInt(input.val()) == input.attr('min')) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
      }

    } else if (type == 'plus') {

      if (currentVal < input.attr('max')) {
        input.val(currentVal + 1).change();

        console.log(currentVal + 1);
      }
      if (parseInt(input.val()) == input.attr('max')) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
      }

    }
  } else {
    input.val(0);
  }

});
$('.input-number').focusin(function() {
  $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val());
});
$('.input-number').change(function() {

  minValue = parseInt($(this).attr('min'));
  maxValue = parseInt($(this).attr('max'));
  valueCurrent = parseInt($(this).val());

  name = $(this).attr('name');
  if (valueCurrent >= minValue) {
    $(".btn-number[data-type='minus'][data-field='" + name + "']").removeAttr('disabled')
  } else {
    alert('Sorry, the minimum value was reached');
    $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue'));
  }
  if (valueCurrent <= maxValue) {
    $(".btn-number[data-type='plus'][data-field='" + name + "']").removeAttr('disabled')
  } else {
    alert('Sorry, the maximum value was reached');
    $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue'));
  }


});
$(".input-number").keydown(function(e) {
  // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
  if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 190]) !== -1 ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+A
    (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
    // Allow: home, end, left, right
    (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
    // let it happen, don't do anything
    return;
  }
  // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
  if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-number"  data-type="minus"  data-field="quant['<?php echo $product['product_id']?>']">
        <span class="fa fa-minus"></span>
    </button>
    </span>
    <input type="text" style="text-align: center" name="quant['<?php echo $product['product_id']?>']" class="form-control input-number" value=" <?php echo $product['quantity']?>" min="1" max="100">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant['<?php echo $product['product_id']?>']">
  <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
    </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку приходит ответ:

```
init [input.form-control.input-number, prevObject: init(1), context: document, selector: "input[name='quant['13079']']"]
```

Как получить значение `'quant['13079']'`?

Comment: `input[name='quant['13079']']` вас с этом селекторе ничего не смущает?

Comment: `var input = $('input[name="' + fieldName + '"]');` или (ES6+) `var input = $(``input[name="${fieldName}"]``);` - во втором случае обратные кавычки должны быть одинарными, это баг(?) местного парсера markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Проще будет добавить инпуту атрибут `ID`

```
<input  id="quant-<?= $product['product_id'] ?>" .... >
....
<button data-field="quant-<?= $product['product_id']?>">...</button>
```

и обращаться по нему:

```
fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
var input = $("#" + fieldName);
```